# GCM RegistrationIntentService getToken at each app startup?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The gcmquickstart tutorial launches the RegistrationServiceIntent at each app startup, is it right to do that and asks InstanceID for a token (even if it is the same) at each run? If yes : could someone explain why? I don't understand why it is necessary.

(Initial question : [GCM token refresh and when to send the token to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357131/gcm-token-refresh-and-when-to-send-the-token-to-server))

Comment: Registering receiver in manifest will call it each time. If you do not want this, you may exclude it from manifest and build your own.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same question, I opened an issue on their github repository to find a more official answer: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/256

On the meantime, I'm storing my token in SharedPreferences and only starting the service if this token is not there. And everything works as expected.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.GCM_TOKEN, "").equals("")) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
}
```

Remember to store the token on `RegistrationIntentService`

```
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Constants.GCM_TOKEN, token).apply();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to store your GCM Connection State in for example a shared preference. Anytime your app lunches you check for the state and act accordingly. For example:

```
boolean sentToken = sp.getBoolean(Extras.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (!sentToken) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegistrationIntentService.class);
                    getActivity().startService(intent);
                }
```

Above you will see that I am checking if The app already has started the service once.

And you would store sentToken state in your service.